# WPF style like css classes

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, tooltip

I have a tooltip style like below:

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                              ...
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

I have two button with each with the defined tooltip but I want only one of them has my tooltip style.

**How can I achieve this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your Tooltip style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}" x:Key="myTooltipStyle">
```

Now, only the button which will specifically ask for the `myTooltipStyle` will get it:

```
<Button ToolTip="{StaticResource myTooltipStyle}">
```